# TreeSet changes/updates size only for last member

Tags: java, collections

So I have to develop this app:

[image]

In my class "Participation" i have this toString:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "[member=" + member.getNameOfMember() + " of " 
           + member.getLocationOfMember()+ ", article=" 
           + article.getName()+ ", party with " 
           + party.getCollParticipation().size() + "members" +"]";
}
```

My Party Class where collParticipation located:

```
package pkgData;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Party implements Serializable, Comparable<Party>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private LocalDate date;
    private TreeSet<Participation> collParticipation;

    public Party(LocalDate date) {
        super();
        this.date = date;
        collParticipation = new TreeSet<>();
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public TreeSet<Participation> getCollParticipation() {
        return collParticipation;
    }

    public void setCollParticipation(TreeSet<Participation> collParticipation) {
        this.collParticipation = collParticipation;
    }

    public void addParticipant(Participation p) throws Exception{
        if(collParticipation.contains(p))
            throw new Exception ("this member is already stored!!");

        if(date.compareTo(p.getParty().getDate())!=0)
            throw new Exception ("date of party of member is not same with party");

        collParticipation.add(p);
        System.out.println(collParticipation);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Party o) {
        return this.getDate().compareTo(o.getDate());
    }   
}
```

And here I add a new party:

```
public void addParty(Party p) throws Exception{
    if(!(collParties.contains(p))){
        collParties.add(p);
    }else{
        Party actParty = collParties.floor(p);      
        for(Participation pcp : p.getCollParticipation()){
           actParty.addParticipant(pcp);  
        }
      } 
    }
```

When I add a Party:

```
    Party newParty = new Party(LocalDate.parse(ftfDateOfParty.getText())); 
    Article a = db.getCollArticels().floor(new Article(nameOfArticle,12,"irgendwas"));
    //splitted String for Name, Location    
    Member m = new Member(splittedMember[0],splittedMember[1]);         
    Participation pm = new Participation(m,a,newParty); 

    newParty.addParticipant(pm);
    db.addParty(newParty);
```

So the problem is:
If I add for example 3 members to the same party the output is always like this:

```
[[member=San of KLfn, article=Buch, party with 1members],
 [member=San of k, article=Buch, party with 1members], 
 [member=Messi of KLfn, article=Buch, party with 3members]]
```

If I print the more participanes from the method addParticipant i get something like this:

```
[[member=uj of ji, article=Buh, party with 1members]
,[member=uj of jdi, article=Buh, party with 1members]
,[member=uj of jdi, article=Buh, party with 1members]
,[member=uj of ji, article=Buh, party with 2members]]
```

The size of the previous members always resets to 1 and only the last member has the actual size of partymembers. I want that every member has the same size of partymembers.

### EDIT

Appearently it only works here:

```
public void addParty(Party p) throws Exception{
    if(!(collParties.contains(p))){
        collParties.add(p);
    }else{
        Party actParty = collParties.floor(p);      
        for(Participation pcp : p.getCollParticipation()){
           actParty.addParticipant(pcp);  
        }
        for(Participation pcp : actParty.getCollParticipation()){
               pcp.setParty(actParty);
        }   
}
```

I have to set the party of "pcp" to the actual party. But why do I get the result that the last member has the actual length of the treeset as if he uses the actParty. Shouldn't he also have the length 1?

Comment: 1. Read [mcve]. 2. Learn how to debug. 3. Good luck!!

Comment: Can you provide information about `getCollParticipation()`? Because it can only happen if there is a error or missvalue update.

Comment: make sure TreeSet create globally

Comment: @GürtuğGüngör It return only the treeset. See edit.

Comment: @ShivaNandam Yes it is globally created

Comment: Then maybe it happens because timing on assignment? or just a miss created or assigned `TreeSet`? And more important what happens when you try with creating more member on a party?

Comment: @GürtuğGüngör You mean more members in same party? The result above is when there are more members in same party.

Comment: Yes, i mean that. According to this, i need to ask more. How do you handle thrown `Exceptions` from `addParticipant(Participation p) throws Exception`? and can you provide more information about `collParticipation` TreeSet?

Comment: BTW, one should neither throw nor catch `Exception`.

Comment: @GürtuğGüngör See edit. Since I have a GUI I have a try catch in my method actionPerformed, so if a error occures I show a error dialog with the exeption message

Comment: I assume that i found your issue but i need one more information about `Comparable<Party>` interface to be sure.

Comment: @GürtuğGüngör What information do you need? I imported Serializable; and use Comparable<Party> just the date of two parties with each other in my class Party

Comment: @GürtuğGüngör See edit

Comment: As i suspected. Thanks for all the information you provide i will post the answer below.

Comment: You're creating a `TreeSet<Participation>`; does `Participation` implement `Comparable<Participation>` or `Comparator<Participation>`?

Comment: @JacobG. Yes it does. It compares the member of participation

Comment: @KeyNavas By the way, in second example you are trying to insert same participant with exact same information, why ? And i have to delete my old answer because i realized it have wrong parts on it